# Zurb Foundation data-topbar stops DIV from being complete

Tags: html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

This is the code that I have for my navigation [in a WordPress site].

```
<div class="sticky">
  <nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-topbar>
    <div class="top_bar_inner">

      <a class="logo" href="<?php echo home_url(''); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
      <?php
        $args = array(
          'theme_location' => 'nav_main',
          'container_class' => 'top-bar-section',
          'container_id' => 'nav_main',
          'menu_class' => 'right',
          'depth' => 1
        );
        wp_nav_menu($args);
      ?>

    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Now the problem is due to the `data-topbar` attribute the `top_bar_inner` DIV class does not wrap the logo and resulting menu items generated by the php code. It only wraps the logo `<a>` tag.

I have also tried `data-topbar="topbar"` but no change. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to have content show on all screen sizes and not fold into the mobile menu, you can do this by adding it as an `<li>` in the title area

```
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"><!-- Leave this empty --></li>
    ...
  </ul>
```

Comment: I am trying to have a DIV inside the top-bar which will contain the logo & menu ul li items.But due to the data-topbar attribute that DIV top_bar_inner does not wrap all the items, it finishes after the logo. Hope I am making sense